# How to present values on an objectListView?

Tags: c#, .net, list, object, objectlistview

I'm using BrightIdeasSoftware's objectListView component, and I want to present a list that I've created. So I have two columns: title, artist.
Next, I wrote a song class:

```
class Song
{
    public Song()
    {

    }

    public Song(string title, string artist)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Artist = artist;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }
    private string title;

    public string Artist
    {
        get { return artist; }
        set { artist = value; }
    }
    private string artist;
}
```

and created a list:

```
        List<Song> songs = new List<Song>();
        Song example = new Song("My Immortal", "Evanescence");
        songs.Add(example);
```

finally, I've called to SetObjects:

```
        objectListView1.SetObjects(songs);
```

But... the problem is that the list is presented to me as an empty list! (I mean, no string is written in run-time...)

Can somebody help me figure out why...?

Answer (score 0):

What did help was to enter the name of the field I wanted to present in the AspectName property.
I mean, "Title" / "Artist". Because they hold string values, I didn't have to enter the "AspectToStringFormat" value.

Answer (score 0):

With the ObjectListView from BrightIdeasSoftware you can provide a delegate for each column that will handle what is displayed.

fx.:

```
var clmTitle = new OLVColumn();

clmTitle.AspectGetter = obj => (obj as Song).Title;


var clmArtist = new OLVColumn();

clmArtist.AspectGetter = obj => (obj as Song).Artist;

objectListView1.Columns.AddRange(new OlVColumn[]{clmTitle,clmArtist});

objectListView1.SetObjects(songs);
```